# How to mock URL with Mockk in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I am trying to mock java.netURL class with Mockk. I dont find any relevant sample to do this.

I want to call below code from test using Mockk

URL(url).host

I tried with below code but not working

```
    val url = mockk<URL>(relaxed = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to mock the results of function calling of this class. For your case, if you want to mock `getHost()` method you need to define it like this:

```
every { mockUrl.host } returns "www.yoururl.com"
```

Comment: I tried but i am getting below error  "class io.mockk.InternalPlatformDsl cannot access a member of class java.net.URL (in module java.base) with modifiers "private"

Comment: Which Java version do you use?

Comment: Mockk: "1.13.3", Kotlin: 1.7.21 and JDK: 17

Answer (score 0):

This is a test that demonstrates mocking an instance of the URL class, with that argument passed, and then specifying that every time this mocks property "host" is accessed / the getter called, this mock will return the string assigned to "url".

```
@Test
fun `verify mockk of URL`() {
    val url = "https://www.whatever.com/gimmeallthejson"
    val mocked = mockk<URL>(relaxed = true)
    every {
        mocked.host
    } returns url

    assertEquals(url, mocked.host)
}
```

If you wanted to mock other values or returns from properties / methods on this mock, simply add more mocked return definitions:

```
 `every { <method or property you wish to mock> } returns / answers <mock values of the type expected>`
```

Here is the Gradle file for an otherwise empty project where this test succeeds for me (project created with JDK 17, Amazon Coretto):

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
    application
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.3")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

Comment: yes i tried. still i am seeing error "java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.mockk.InternalPlatformDsl cannot access a member of class java.net.URL (in module java.base) with modifiers "private"

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?